# how get json source of deserialized object? json.net

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

im using json.net

After deserializing of json to object, i want to get json source of this object

e.g.

```
objParent:{
  objChild1: {name:"testObj"},
  objChild2: {age: 25}
}
```

in c# code

```
public ObjChild1
{
  public string name {get;set;}

  [JsonIgnore]
  public string JsonSource { get; set; }    //objChild1: {name:"testObj"}
}

public ObjChild2
{
  public int age {get;set;}

  [JsonIgnore]
  public string JsonSource { get; set; }   //objChild2: {age: 25}   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have json.net installed but with the standard classes you can simply serialize the individual object back to a JSON string, like this:

```
...
    public static class JSONHelper
    {
        public static string ToJSONString(this object obj)
        {
            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            return serializer.Serialize(obj);
        }
    }
...

    public ObjChild1
    {
        public string name {get;set;}

        [ScriptIgnore]
        public string JsonSource { get { return this.ToJSONString(); } }
    }    

    public class ObjChild2
    {
        public int age {get;set;}

        [ScriptIgnore]
        public string JsonSource { get { return this.ToJSONString(); } }
    }
```